# Selecting records on condition - Joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla

I followed Joomla doc about how to select data from a single table. I need 3 OR conditions.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('column1', 'column2', 'column3' )));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__table_example'));

$query->where($db->quoteName('column1') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('condition1'));
OR where column2 == condition2
...
```

How to make where statement with many ORs in my example? I didn't find any topics on syntax correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add or conditions in the same where statement :

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('column1', 'column2', 'column3' )));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__table_example'));

$query->where($db->quoteName('column1') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('condition1') . ' OR ' . $db->quoteName('column2') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('condition2') . ' OR ' . $db->quoteName('column3') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('condition3') );
```

Answer (score 1):

I give a general answer which will cover not only **OR** but also several **AND** problems. Use **WHERE** query like this:
ex: query should run if one of (cond1 or cond2 or cond3) is true AND one of (cond4 or cond5 is true):

```
$query->where( ( (cond1)OR(cond2)OR(cond3) ) AND ( (cond4)OR(cond5) ) );
```

So you can use **OR** and **AND** any how you like, just be sure that you use `()` properly to define your condition.

In your particular case, you will use format like this:

```
$query->where( (var LIKE cond1) OR (cond2) );
```

obviously your cond2 is: `column2 == condition2`

*I hope it resolves confusion.*